# How to access redux connect mapStateToProps without a rerender

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to use a `mousedown` event to close an autocomplete when the user clicks outside of the input.

code:

```
// listen to mouse clicking outside of autocomplete or input
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutsideAutocomplete);

  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutsideAutocomplete);
  };
}, []);

const handleClickOutsideAutocomplete = (e) => {
  console.log("props:", props);
  const { current: wrap } = wrapperRef;

  if (wrap && !wrap.contains(e.target)) {
    setisOpen(false);
  }
};
```

This code runs as expected. However, when I try to access `props` on the `mousedown` event passed via react-redux `connect`, they are all null. The props passed from the parent component however are present. I have confirmed that on the initial render the react-redux `connect` props are there as expected.

I thought the `mousedown` event may be something to do with it so I tested accessing react-redux `connect` `props` using a timeout as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("The connect props are all null", props);
  }, 5000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, []);
```

The react-redux `connect` `props` here are also null.

Is it possible to access `connect` `props` after the initial render, i.e., on a timeout or `mousedown` event?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you haven't added the `handleClickOutsideAutocomplete` function in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook and because of the closure, event handler function doesn't sees the updated value of props.

#### Solution

Add the `handleClickOutsideAutocomplete` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook and also wrap `handleClickOutsideAutocomplete` in the `useCallback` hook to avoid running the `useEffect` hook everytime your component re-renders. Also don't forget to list the required dependencies in the dependency array of the `useCallback` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [handleClickOutsideAutocomplete]);        

const handleClickOutsideAutocomplete = useCallback((e) => {
  ...
}, [props]);
```

React recommends to use [`exhaustive-deps rule`](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) as part of their [`eslint-plugin-react-hooks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks#installation) package. It warns whenever you omit or incorrectly specify a dependency and also suggests a fix.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent answer and clearly stated. Much appreciated.